# Swift CoreBluetooth: why I do not find the same characteristic as my bluetooth peripheral?

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, core-bluetooth

I'm starting with the bluetooth as a project car Arduino controlled by an iPhone.
The problem is that I try to send a single data from my iphone but looking more closely at the scan function is not good caracteristic and I think the problem comes from here.
Have you an idea to find the same in their characteristic UUID?

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

@IBOutlet weak var peripheralLabel: UILabel!
//713D0000503E4C75BA943148F18D941E

let BEAN_NAME = "Carduino"
let CBUUIDUuidTx = CBUUID(string: "713D0000-503E-4C75-BA94-3148F18D941E")
let CBUUIDUuIdRx = CBUUID(string: "713D0000-503E-4C75-BA94-3148F18D941E")
let UuidTx = "713D0000-503E-4C75-BA94-3148F18D941E"
let UuIdRx = "713D0000-503E-4C75-BA94-3148F18D941E"

var peripheralBLE: CBPeripheral?
var manager:CBCentralManager!
var myPeripheral:CBPeripheral!
var sendDataCharacteristic:CBCharacteristic!
var txCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic!
var rxCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

//Scan For devices
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) { 
    manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUIDUuidTx], options: nil)
}

//Connect to a Device
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary)
        .object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
        as? NSString

    if device?.contains(BEAN_NAME) == true {
        self.manager.stopScan()

        self.myPeripheral = peripheral
        self.myPeripheral.delegate = self

        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        peripheralLabel.text = "Connect to \(peripheral.name!)"
    }
}

//Get Services
func centralManager(
    _ central: CBCentralManager,
    didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

//Get Characteristics
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        let thisService = service as CBService

        if service.uuid == CBUUIDUuidTx {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(
                nil,
                for: thisService
            )
        }
        print("This Service : \(thisService)")
    }        
}

func peripheral( _ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {     
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        let thisCharacteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic

        if thisCharacteristic.uuid == CBUUIDUuidTx {
            self.myPeripheral.setNotifyValue(
                true,
                for: thisCharacteristic
            )
        }
        print("This Characteristic : \(thisCharacteristic)")
    }

}

//Disconnect and Try Again
func centralManager(
    _ central: CBCentralManager,
    didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                            error: Error?) {
    central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
}

@IBAction func ledAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    writeValue(data: "0x01")
}

func writeValue(data: String) {        
    if(myPeripheral != nil)
    {
        print(myPeripheral)
        //happens for sure
        var bytesData = [UInt8](data.utf8)
        let writeData = NSData (bytes: &bytesData, length: bytesData.count)
        myPeripheral.writeValue(writeData as Data, for: txCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        print(txCharacteristic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your issue exactly? On `writeValue()`? Where did you set `txCharacteristic`?

Comment: Are you using a LightBlue bean?  If so, there is a framework for it that makes all of this a lot easier.  Also, once you have discovered your peripheral through a scan, you can store its `identifier` and then just issue a `connect` directly if you disconnect; no need to scan again.

Comment: In `didUpdateState` you shouldn't scan until you are in the .poweredOn state. Are you sure that the peripheral's service that you are interested in and the service's characteristic have the same UUID?  What exactly happens when you run your code?

Comment: Sorry Larme txCharacteristic is in "didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor" function after "if thisCharacteristic.uuid == CBUUIDUuidTx". But when i run my code, it happens i print each Characteristic from "didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor" function to integrate in txCharacteristic but no one is the UUID to my arduino.

my arduino is uno with redbearlab shield bluetooth.

Comment: no one have a advice ?